# Grails Projects require to re-start after each change in the controller

Tags: grails

I am working to develop a project in Grails 3.1 and using IntelliJ 2016. I am new to Grails.

I have a problem as each time I make a change in controller or service I need to re-run the project otherwise it wont reflect the changes.

I tried to delete all the things in target folder and also performed grails clean but still the problem is there.

Comment: How do you run the project?  Have you tried with the more recent 3.2 version of Grails?

Comment: I run the project through intellij .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i fixed it it has problem with the path to the project as discussed in this linkhttps://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9344

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-run after changes. You need to `save` and `rebuild project` from 'Build' Toolbar then it will take effect.

Comment: Grails itself already runs spring-loaded and watches for changes in your source locations.  Saving a file is enough to make a reload happening.

Comment: as soon as i save a change in file it recompiles but when i refresh the page the chnages doesnot reflets and i have to re run the project

Comment: If the changes happen in Domain Class then you need to re-run project otherwise you can see affect on Rebuild.

Comment: But my case is whatever chnage i make in controller or service i need to re run the project even building the project does not solve the issue.